# Haskell Show type class in a function

Tags: haskell

I have a function

```
mySucc :: (Enum a, Bounded a, Eq a, Show a) => a -> Maybe a
mySucc int 
     | int == maxBound = Nothing
     | otherwise = Just $ succ int
```

When I want to print the output of this function in ghci, Haskell seems to be confused as to which instance of Show to use. Why is that? Shouldn't Haskell automatically resolve a's type during runtime and use it's Show?

My limited understanding of type class is that, if you mention a type (in my case a) and say that it belongs to a type class (Show), Haskell should automatically resolve the type. Isn't that how it resolves Bounded, Enum and Eq? Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: How are you calling this function in GHCi?

Comment: Hi, it is by using "stack ghci"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Shouldn't Haskell automatically resolve a's type during runtime and use it's `Show`?

Generally speaking, types *don't exist* at runtime. The compiler typechecks your code, resolves any polymorphism, and then erases the types. But, this is kind of orthogonal to your main question.

> My limited understanding of type class is that, if you mention a type (in my case `a`) and say that it belongs to a type class (`Show`), Haskell should automatically resolve the type

No. The compiler will automatically resolve *the instance*. What that means is, you don't need to explicitly pass a showing-method into your function. For example, instead of the function

```
showTwice :: Show a => a -> String
showTwice x = show x ++ show x
```

you could have a function that doesn't use any typeclass

```
showTwice' :: (a -> String) -> a -> String
showTwice' show' x = show' x ++ show' x
```

which can be used much the same way as `showTwice` if you give it the standard `show` as the first argument. But that argument would need to be manually passed around at each call site. *That's* what you can avoid by using the type class instead, but this still requires the *type* to be known first.

(Your `mySucc` doesn't actually use `show` in any way *at all*, so you might as well omit the `Show a` constraint completely.)

When your call to `mySucc` appears in a larger expression, chances are the type *will* in fact also be inferred automatically. For example, `mySucc (length "bla")` will use `a ~ Int`, because the result of `length` is fixed to `Int`; or `mySucc 'y'` will use `a ~ Char`. However, if *all* the subexpressions are polymorphic (and in Haskell, even number literals are polymorphic), then the compiler won't have any indication what type you actually want. In that case you can always specify it explicitly, either in the argument

```
> mySucc (3 :: Int)
Just 4
```

or in the result

```
> mySucc 255 :: Maybe Word8
Nothing
```

Comment: Now I understand that when we use "test :: (Eq a) -> a -> a", it means a is of any instance that implements all (mandatory) methods described in Eq. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: Yes. I basically just means you will be able to use `==` inside the definition of `test`, even though you don't know what type it is at that point. But the compiler does need to know the type, when `test` is used in an actual program.

Answer (score 2):

Are you writing `mySucc 1`? In this case, you get a error because `1` literal is a polymorphic value of type `Num a => a`.

Try calling `mySucc 1 :: Maybe Int` and it will work.